# With Ruby 1.8.7 do a regex replace when string is not bound with particular text?

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, regex-negation

A given- I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and therefor can't use negative lookbehind. I'm also aware of [oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/oniguruma/) but am looking for solutions without it.

If I have:

```
foo = "string and string [foo and string stuff] string and strings foostring string"
w = "string"
```

How can I modify this:

```
foo.gsub(/\b#{w}\b/i) {|s| "[#{w}]"}
```

So that the 'string' enclosed anywhere between [] is not matched, e.g the desired result is:

```
"[string] and [string] [foo and string stuff] [string] and strings foostring [string]"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the square brackets will always occur in balanced pairs as they do in your example, you can do a negative lookahead for an unbalanced closing bracket after the word.  If the opening bracket isn't *after* the word, it must be *before* the word.  Example:

```
foo.gsub(/\b#{w}\b(?![^\[]*\])/) {|s| "[#{w}]"}
```

Another option is to match **either** a pair of brackets and everything inside them, **or** the target string.  If it's a bracketed sequence you matched, you plug it right back in; otherwise you add brackets to the matched string and plug *that* in.  In this case it's even simpler: you can just capture everything *inside* the brackets in one group, or the target string in another group, then use the `\+` metasequence to plug in the contents of whichever group matched, with brackets added.  Example:

```
foo.gsub(/\[([^\]\[]*)\]|(\b#{w}\b)/, '[\+]')
```

[**see them in action on ideone**](http://ideone.com/pwtWd)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot prove that what you ask for cannot be done with a single regexp, but I don't believe that it is possible. However, here is how you could accomplish it:

```
foo = "string and string [foo and string stuff] string and strings foostring string"
w = "string"

brackets = []
a = foo.gsub( /\[[^\]]+\]/ ){ |b| brackets << b; "-^#{brackets.length-1}^-" }
b = a.gsub(/\b#{w}\b/i) {|s| "[#{w}]" }
c = b.gsub( /-\^\d+\^-/ ){ |s| brackets[ s[/\d+/].to_i ] }

p a, b, c
#=> "string and string -^0^- string and strings foostring string"
#=> "[string] and [string] -^0^- [string] and strings foostring [string]"
#=> "[string] and [string] [foo and string stuff] [string] and strings foostring [string]"
```

Comment: Thanks much Phrogz, I was in the process of stumbling to the same conclusion and working on a multi-part solution similar as well. As a side question- do you think it's possible with negative/positive look around?